# Deadlock Problem because of an Update Lock

Tags: sql-server

We have a deadlock issue we're trying to track down. I have an deadlock graph (xdl) generated from Profiler. It shows the losing SQL statement as a simple Select statement, not an Update, Delete or Insert statement. The graph shows the losing Select statement as requesting a Shared lock on a resource `**but also owning an Update lock on a resource**`. This is what is baffling me. Why would a Select statement that is not part of an Insert, Update or Delete ever hold an Update lock on a resource?

I should add that the Update lock it owns is on the table being selected against by the losing Select statement.

EDIT: Please don't suggest using NoLock. Yes that would solve the problem but introduces a new one - a dirty read issue. This query is hitting a production server. What I really want to know is why would a Select statement issue an Update lock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You sure the SELECT *owns* the U lock?

As you know, U and X locks (as well as serializable S locks) are held for the duration of the *transaction*, not the statement. So it is perfectly possible for a transaction that issued a write to own a U lock, from a previously executed statement. Why it would own a U lock, as opposed to an X lock (ie. it owns a U lock *that was not upgraded to an X*), is a bit of a puzzle in itself, but I can envision couple of ways this can happen.
So it is perfectly possible to have a SELECT statement to own X/U locks if it is part of a multi-statement transaction. A standalone SELECT with a U lock under its belt, that is a bit unusual I reckon.

The typical SELECT vs. UPDATE deadlock occurs on index access order scenarios, like the one described in [Read/Write deadlock](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/). I trust you did a diligent read of the deadlock graph, but if it's not too much to ask, can you share it?

Oh, and btw, have you considered read committed snapshot?

Comment: I'd be glad to share it. How should I do so?

Comment: If you can't share it online, send it to me. My email is on the contact page on my site http://rusanu.com/contact-us

Comment: I just it to the email address on your contact page.

Answer (score 1):

A `select` statement does create a shared lock. Try `select` with the `nolock` hint. It would solve the problem.

For example:

```
select * from table(nolock)
```

Comment: @Byron - Yes I know a Select creates a Shared lock. My question concerns an Update lock. And NoLock solves one problem and introduces another. It solves the locking issue and introduces a dirty read issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the select was invoked with UPDLOCK hint?
Anyway, can you use snapshot isolation and eliminate the problem?